# data dots shift when using cartodb.js

Tags: carto, carto-js, wordpress

[image: As you can see this is a tutorial example map.]

As you can see this is a tutorial example map. It works strangely on my own website. The Florida location is now shifting down a little bit. In fact, all of the dots shift down a little bit.

How do I implement it?
I simply copy the js code. And use wp_enqueue_scripts to include the cartodb.js and my own js. Since the map not shows up if I use `width: 100%; height: 100%;` so I explicitly set the px in css file like this:

```
#casemap{width: 1000px; height: 600px; background: black;}
```

Here is my php code.

```
<?php /* Template Name: Casemap */ 
get_header(); ?>
    <header class="page-header">
        <h1 class="page-header-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    </header>
    <div id='casemap'></div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

PS, No JS error in my browser console.

Here is the tutorial website:
http://docs.cartodb.com/tutorials/create_map_cartodbjs.html

Here is url to the tutorial code:
http://cartodb.s3.amazonaws.com/static/tutorial_files/cartodbjs_tutorial_create_map.zip

Comment: Could you send us the link to your website?

Comment: Sure. http://foodenergysystems.net/wp/?page_id=8281. BTW, same thing happen when I am using my own map. And if you use IE, the shift issue is even more obvious.

Comment: It's working fine in my Chrome 39.0.2171.99 over MacOSX. Could you send us the information from your system and browser? http://www.whatsmybrowser.org/

Comment: That's quite interesting. On my win8.1 I use chrome, firefox and ie, non of them work properly. But when I use firefox and chrome in my ubuntu, it is actually fine.

Comment: what do you mean with "shifting down"?

Comment: As you can see from the screenshot, the info window pop up at a place where there is no dot. If you have a windows OS, you might try it through the link I post in the previous conversation.

Answer (score 0):

Turn out something wrong when the wordpress admin bar on the top shows up. I guess it has something to with the coordinates they are using. My temporary solution is to disable wordpress admin bar for normal users.